# Data fitting using fmin from scipy.optimize under jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, regression

I'm trying

**Data fitting using fmin**
http://glowingpython.blogspot.ca/2011/05/curve-fitting-using-fmin.html

Which contains the following code to use `fmin`:

```
# fitting the data with fmin
p0 = rand(3) # initial parameter value
p = fmin(e, p0, args=(x,y))
```

However, it is giving me the following error when I try it:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-41b53befd463> in <module>()
     22 # fitting the data with fmin
     23 p0 = rand(3) # initial parameter value
---> 24 p = fmin(e, p0, args=(x,y))
     25 
     26 print 'estimater parameters: ', p

TypeError: 'args' is an invalid keyword to ufunc 'fmin'
```

When I looked at doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html), I do see the `args` is a valid keyword.

**UPDATE**:

I was running the script as-is in Python2.7, and got the above error. 
Having seen Warren Weckesser's answer here is the updated script:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import normal
from scipy.optimize import fmin

%pylab inline

# parametric function, x is the independent variable
# and c are the parameters.
# it's a polynomial of degree 2
fp = lambda c, x: c[0]+c[1]*x+c[2]*x*x
real_p = rand(3)

# error function to minimize
e = lambda p, x, y: (abs((fp(p,x)-y))).sum()

# generating data with noise
n = 30
x = linspace(0,1,n)
y = fp(real_p,x) + normal(0,0.05,n)

# fitting the data with fmin
p0 = rand(3) # initial parameter value
p = fmin(e, p0, args=(x,y))

print 'estimater parameters: ', p
print 'real parameters: ', real_p

xx = linspace(0,1,n*3)
plot(x,y,'bo', xx,fp(real_p,xx),'g', xx, fp(p,xx),'r')

show()
```

and I'm still getting the exact same error as above.

How to fix it? Thx.

Comment: So you did some changes to that code? Show it! This code copy-pasted should work! (I hope you did not name your file fmin.py)

Comment: <sigh> "_should work_", at least I tried it, not just think it should work or not.

Comment: When I remove the line `%pylab inline` and run that script, it works for me.  How are you running the code?

Comment: Are you using a jupyter notebook?  If so, `%pylab inline` will cause `fmin` to be replaced by `numpy.fmin`.  In fact, when I do that, it gives me a warning message (with a red background) telling me that `"pylab import has clobbered these variables: ['fmin']"`.

Comment: Yes @WarrenWeckesser, exactly, I'm using jupyter notebook, which output warning message in red background all the time. I got that `clobbered` warning as well, but wasn't able to interpret what exactly does it mean. Thanks for getting to the bottom of it. So does it means that I can't use jupyter notebook, at least in `%pylab inline` mode?

Comment: @xpt See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduced the problem.  Without that, we have to guess.

In this case, my guess is that you are actually using [`numpy.fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fmin.html), not [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html).  Add the line

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
```

at the top of your script.  And if you are doing something like

```
from numpy import *
```

(as the code at `glowingpython` does), then remove that line, and either use

```
import numpy as np
```

and use the `np.` prefix with all the numpy names that you use, or explicitly import only those names from numpy that you actually use, e.g.

```
from numpy import array, linspace  # whatever you actually use
from numpy.random import rand      # etc.
```

Using the `*` form of `import` is a bad practice in scripts, for exactly the reason that you have this question.

It is true, however, that something like `from pylab import *` is very convenient when you are working interactively in ipython or in a jupyter notebook.  To avoid the problem of `fmin` being shadowed by the `fmin` from numpy, you could do:

```
from scipy import optimize
```

and then call `fmin` using

```
p = optimize.fmin(e, p0, args=(x, y))
```